# Gratis Vax 11780 emulator

Tags: gratis, emulator, vax

I am seeking a [gratis](/questions/tagged/gratis) Vax 11780 emulator.

Preferably running on Windows; Linux is also acceptable, in a fact anything with a gratis virtual machine to run the emulator (or, the emulator itself as a VM).

Comment: I haven't done any detailed investigation, but a cursory Google search to a couple of dead pages led me to try the [wayback machine for www.aracnet.com/~healyzh/vax.html](http://web.archive.org/web/*/www.aracnet.com/~healyzh/vax.html) - does this have anything helpful for you?

Comment: "Sorry. Wayback Machine failed to return archive information."  :-(

Comment: I had to edit that link several times; markdown was doing funny things to it. The link as it CURRENTLY is should work, or just manually paste www.aracnet.com/~healyzh/vax.html into its search field.